# get not matched strings using NSPredicate for Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have

```
  Array
  Item 0 -- Dictionary
    name -- String
    phoneNumbers  -- Array
      Item 0 -- string
   Item 1 -- Dictionary
      And so on.....
```

I would like to create a `NSPredicate` select `phoneNumbers` that are not in a given array inside of `phoneNumbers` array. How can I achieve reaching that deep?

If you cannot understand the graph. I have an array full of dictionaries, Inside the dictionaries are A string and An Array of strings

So How do I get into the second strings(array of strings) **phoneNumbers** and get the phoneNumbers that are not in a given  array of strings **givenPhoneNumbers** using `NSPredicate`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so are there 2 different phoneNumbers array?

Comment: please distinguish with different names it is confusing

Comment: yes there are deferent

Comment: and you need only phone numbers? right?

Comment: YES I need only phoneNumbers

Comment: check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35843544/2963912

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    NSMutableArray *arrItems; //set ur dict data;
    NSMutableArray *givenPhoneNumbers; //set phone numbers array;
  NSMutableArray *requiredPhoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];

  [arrItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx,
                                         BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {

    [requiredPhoneNumbers
        addObjectsFromArray:
            [[obj objectForKey:@"phoneNumbers"]
                filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (Self IN %@)",
                                                     givenPhoneNumbers]]];
  }];
```

Comment: anytime, happy to help

Comment: this was helpful for me